# NSValueTransformer, inserting NULL into core data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I'm having a problem with NSValueTransformer, instead of transforming the value (NSString) it's putting NULL into the database where the attributes are transformable. I'm using the apple example, which is the same are everyone else's example and I just can't get it to work on a simple level. I'm also putting breakpoints at transformedValue and reverseTransformedValue, but they never get hit.

My custom class

```
  + (void)registerValueTransformer {
      [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:[[[self alloc] init] autorelease] forName:@"myTransformerTest"];
  }

  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark NSValueTransformer implementation

  + (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
      return YES;
  }

  + (Class)transformedValueClass {
      return [NSString class];
  }

  - (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
      return @"Test in";
  }

  - (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
      return @"Test Out";
  }
```

And this in my app delegate

```
  +(void) initialize 
  {
      [super initialize];

      [transformerTest registerValueTransformer];
  }
```

And then in Core data I've made my attribute transformable with a name "myTransformerTest". And according to the apple documentation that should be it.